# Can you embed a php instruction in html that is embedded in php?

Tags: php, html

I tried something like this:

```
// $count is an incrementing number
echo '<td><input type = "radio" name = "selected" 
      value = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($count); ?>"></td>';
```

I also tried:

```
echo '<td><input type = "radio" name = "selected" value = "<?php echo 
"$count"; ?>"></td>';
```

and neither worked. I realize it may seem strange to attempt to write html with php in this way, but I don't know how else to display html based off certain conditions.

Adding entire function that snippet is in:

```
function makeRow($row_name,$row_ticket) {
//create html table row from mysql table row passed as ticket object param
$count = 0;
foreach ($row_array as $key => $value) {
   # code...
   $count++;
   if(strcmp($key, "select")==0){
     echo '<td><input type = "radio" name = "selected" 
     value ="' . <?php echo htmlspecialchars($count); ?> . '"></td>';
   }
   else if(strcmp($key, "body")==0){/*do not make cell for body*/}

   else { echo "<td>$value</td>";}
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot work because you can't concatenate a string like that it throws php parse error. I have not enough reputation for commenting so I add my own answer:

```
// $count is an incrementing number
echo '<td><input type = "radio" name = "selected" 
value ="' . htmlspecialchars($count) . '"></td>';
```

You can't add new php open/close tag inside another one.

> Update:

Actually, you don't need htmlspecialchars() function for just outputing script - generated integer variable, so you can skip that too.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize i didn't need the script tags!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just concatenate the string and the embedded `<?php`:

```
// $count is an incrementing number
echo '<td><input type = "radio" name = "selected" 
    value ="' . <?php echo htmlspecialchars($count); ?> . '"></td>';
```

---

**NOTE:** I also think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of where the PHP and HTML are interpreted:

1. PHP is a **server-side** scripting language designed for web development... (see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)). That means that the PHP code will be executed on the server before arriving in the browser.
2. HTML is interpreted as plain text by the browser. No PHP is executed in the browser. Your HTML will look like this when interpreted by the browser:

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="selected" value="<?php echo "$count"; ?>">
</td>
```

Comment: He was probably just hoping that there was an easy way out ;)

Comment: @jsve This did not work unfortunately.@flyinheagle413 And I'm not sure what you mean by an easy way out?

Comment: @Devin_Kinh, if that didn't work, can you please add some context to your question? What does the surrounding code look like?

Comment: @jsve I added the function I was using it in.